# Emmet wrap and Find match occurences - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

While wrapping found occurences in emmet, I would like to have a reference to the occurence position

let's say we have a text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet *hello world* consectetur adipisicing elit.
Inventore distinctio recusandae ea autem dolore quaerat placeat debitis error, fugit *hello world* et id dicta eum, mollitia, amet cum ducimus nihil *hello world* laborum. Error.

hello world occurs 3 times

When I wrap occurences with emmet

```
span#helloworld$
```

I end up with helloworld1 three times

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span id="helloworld1">hello world</span> consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Inventore distinctio recusandae ea autem dolore quaerat placeat debitis error, fugit <span id="helloworld1">hello world</span> et id dicta eum, mollitia, amet cum ducimus nihil <span id="helloworld1">hello world</span> laborum. Error.
```

whereas I would like to end up with helloworld1 ...2 ...3

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span id="helloworld1">hello world</span> consectetur adipisicing elit. 
Inventore distinctio recusandae ea autem dolore quaerat placeat debitis error, fugit <span id="helloworld2">hello world</span> et id dicta eum, mollitia, amet cum ducimus nihil <span id="helloworld3">hello world</span> laborum. Error.
```